# Testing in app billing

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I uploaded my signed app to the android market, I made some in app contents that I've published (but not the app).
Now I trying to purchase my own products on a real device: do I need to test with the same signed .apk I uploaded to the market? Or a "normal" one I can launch with Eclipse?

Cause when I launch my app with Eclipse and send a requestPurchase(), a pop up tells me that this app version is not ready for market purchase...

> You do not need to publish your application to perform end-to-end testing with real product IDs; you only need to upload your application as a draft application. However, you must sign your application with your release key before you upload it as a draft application. Also, the version number of the uploaded application must match the version number of the application you load to your device for testing.

And as it's write on google's doc, the version number of the app on the market and of the app on the device are the same :/

Comment: Yes as per my knowledge you will need same apk file. Have you tried with same apk?

Comment: for more reference you refer this link 
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a signed APK, the same one you uploaded to the app market.

You also need to use a different gmail account to your developer account to access the market.

There's a good tutorial here: [Simple In App Billing](http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html) with some alternative explanations

The testing developer guide is pretty thorough: [Testing Billing Statically](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static)

Comment: that means that for every change I made in the code, I need to re-export the .apk, re-upload it in the market and in the device?

Comment: You can test the signed APK without uploading it to the market. Just put the APK on the phones' sd card and install it from there. Other testing should be done using 'android.test.purchased'. You don't have to test with your own items every time.

Comment: so I only need to upload my app only once at the beginning to create my products, and after if I change some code, just export it with Eclipse and put it on the phone sd card?

Comment: For testing. yes. But once you have tested your real products once, you may as well use the 'android.test.purchase' to imitate a successful purchase, that way you can use the eclipse debug build.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to sign the apk (in Eclipse : Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package...) and reinstall it on the device (with the device attached to USB : adb install _YOUR_APK_).

There's also a way to test your app on the emulator with your own products before going to the real money : [android test billing](http://code.google.com/p/android-test-billing/) library.
This library is the In-App billing implementation for the emulator, which was tested in the application Horer [horaires de RER](http://www.horer.fr).